# Get hextop self-organizing map neuron connections

Tags: matlab, neural-network, self-organizing-maps

How do I get a n-by-2 vector that contains the connections of the neurons in an SOM? For example, if I have a simple 2x2 hextop SOM, the connections vector should look like:

`[
1 2
1 3
1 4
]`

This vector indicates that the neuron 1 is connected to neuron 2, neuron 1 is connected to neuron 3, etc.

How can this connections vector be retrieved from any given SOM?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with [`selforgmap`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/selforgmap.html), which I assume you're using, but looking at the code for [`plotsomnc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/plotsomnc.html), would `sparse(tril(net.layers{1}.distances <= 1.001)-eye(net.layers{1}.size))` give you what you want? Otherwise, it would help us if you provided a basic runnable example of how you set up your SOM network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the SOM is defined with neighbourhood distance 1 (i.e., for each neuron, edges to all neurons within an Euclidian distance of 1), the default option for Matlabs `hextop(...)` command, you can create your connections vector as follows:

```
pos = hextop(2,2);

% Find neurons within a Euclidean distance of 1, for each neuron.

% option A: count edges only once
distMat = triu(dist(pos));
[I, J] = find(distMat > 0 & distMat <= 1);
connectionsVectorA = [I J]

% option B: count edges in both directions
distMat = dist(pos);
[I, J] = find(distMat > 0 & distMat <= 1);
connectionsVectorB = sortrows([I J])

% verify graphically
plotsom(pos)
```

The output from the above follows:

```
connectionsVectorA =

     1     2
     1     3
     2     3
     2     4
     3     4


connectionsVectorB =

     1     2
     1     3
     2     1
     2     3
     2     4
     3     1
     3     2
     3     4
     4     2
     4     3
```

If you have a SOM with a non-default neighbourhood distance (`!= 1`), say `nDist`, just replace the `find(..)` commands above with

```
... find(distMat > 0 & distMat <= nDist);
```

Comment: @BrianGoodwin Happy to help.